# Field level permission in Azure DevOps for particular users

Tags: azure-devops

I have a scenario in which only admins can edit few of work Item fields, not all users should be able to edit the fields but I didn't find any way in which I can do this or if the field value is set, it shouldn't be changed again.

Answer (score 0):

***Depending on the field***, you can use **Rules** on the work item to make a field read only after it has been given a value.

I have found work item rules to be lacking in functionality for many of the situations I've tried to use them, but sometimes it works well enough.

[image]

If the field needs to be edited a different time you would need to hack another rule in based on some other controlling value to allow the field to be made editable again.

Comment: I tried this rule but it is not allowing me to set the value for the first time, throws an exception of ReadOnlyField through rest API, also not allowing to enter the value for   first time through interface, I just want to enter a field values while creation of the work item, then it should not be editable, can you please help me with that?

Comment: You might need to use a different condition. The field probably already has a value, so you might need to use **When:** `A change was made to the value of...`